# Ruby version mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, bundler

When I go to my projects folder and type in

```
rails s
```

I get the following error message:

```
Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

I specified the ruby version (for Heroku) in my Gemfile like this:

```
ruby "2.0.0"
```

I found this issue on Github:

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/400

The issue is described as kind of a mess added by the Heroku Toolbelt by adding their own folder at the beginning of the $PATH environment variable. I already tried to implement the solution provided by the issue closer, but I could not bring it to work.

Here are the last lines of my ~/.bashrc file

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

and here is what I get for echo $PATH

```
/home/user/.rbenv/shims:/home/user/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

and for ruby -v

```
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [i686-linux]
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this blog post, I think this is the answer for you. I had the same problem before so I specified the ruby version it worked afterwards.

http://cbednarski.com/articles/installing-ruby/

Comment: Sorry, but this does not help me since I installed ruby this way already. I forgot to mention on my answer that I'm using rbenv and I set the project specific ruby version by typing rbenv local 2.0.0-p195